# Started writing my first php game application

Tags: php

Hello i am very new on developing application. I have worked with my friend web application, Now i want to build my own web application so i was wondering what developing software i must use. What will be first thing i will start with and so on.

should i start with php or css or js?

I used **Notepad+** most of time writing my codes. Im not familiar with other software. And some time used online : `http://jsfiddle.net/`

Well if you guys can provide some good information on developing software that will help me alot in future.

```
Want to know best php writing software  

Want to know best js writing software 

Want to know best css writing software
```

I know firebug is best for debugging.

Comment: I think you should look at Zend Studio : http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/ Or Netbeans : http://netbeans.org/

Comment: aptana studio (eclipse) for web applications (php, css, js, html etc) http://www.aptana.com

Comment: I will try both and try to get familiar with any one  Zend Studio and aptana studio thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i has been a professional web developer(html/css/javascript/php).
I would highly recommend you Netbeans IDE 7.2. It is a great ide that
has everything you  might be looking for. Code Highlighting, Syntax coloring, auto complete, debugging capabilities, multiple programming languages, sql manager, web services manager,
integration with svn and git, etc..
It will allow you to edit all your files(html,css,javascript,php,sql) in the same place.

AND ITS FREE!!

Comment: Thanks brother i will try is first. free is more better for newbie

Comment: Everytime I hear somebody say they are a professional developer I am eager to see their GitHub profile for some reason. :-)

Comment: And im excited to see how much down my this question goes. ITS NOT GOOD TO ASK simple question?

Comment: It's fine to ask simple question, but your question is just a bad one for SO according to [our faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: What a shame that now for being a good developer is a requirement to have a GitHub profile. Poor guys that have the knowledge to host their own repositories on their own servers and don't have to use a public one. They are no longer professional developers, because of you opinion.

Comment: Its not compulsory to have GitHub anyways